# Falha ao excluir usando eclipselink

Tags: banco-de-dados

Boa tarde pessoal.

Estou dando manutenção em um sistema que outro desenvolvedor começou, antes ele estava usando o hibernate e depois migrou para o eclipselink.

Quando estava usando o hibernate estava funcionando normal, e quando migrou começou a falhar o delete.

O Controller está assim.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {deletePath}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String delete(@PathVariable("id") String id, Division division) {
       divisionService.delete(division);
       return "redirect:"+defaultPath;
}
```

stackoverflow

> Erro: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint Detalhe: Failing row contains (d1ba96c6-baac-4664-86f1-af22386324bd, AB8D5E1F-66C1-40F9-B98E-DEC21FFA7626, null, null, d1ba96c6-baac-4664-86f1-af22386324bc, 2015-03-27 11:42:27.427, d1ba96c6-baac-4664-86f1-af22386324bc, 2015-03-27 12:27:29.097, f). Error Code: 0 Call: UPDATE _login.division SET ACTIVE = ?, MODIFIEDBY = ?, MODIFIEDON = ?, NAME = ?, parent = ? WHERE (id = ?) bind => [false, d1ba96c6-baac-4664-86f1-af22386324bc, 2015-03-27 12:27:29.097, null, null, AB8D5E1F-66C1-40F9-B98E-DEC21FFA7626] Query: UpdateObjectQuery(com.xphub.core.model.Division@7cc1d214)
>   URL: http://localhost:8080/xphub/admin/user/division/AB8D5E1F-66C1-40F9-B98E-DEC21FFA7626/delete

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho todo o código para afirmar 100% qual o problema, mas me parece que sua classe `DivisionService` está tentando dar um update na entidade `Division` recebida pelo ser controlador.

Provavelmente esse sistema é daqueles que não apaga realmente os dados, apenas altera uma *flag* para desabilitar ou desativar o registro que não será mais exibido.

Ao tentar atualizar o objeto, provavelmente chamando o método *merge*, o EclipseLink validou novamente a entidade e viu que os dados não estavam preenchidos. Isso ocorre provavelmente porque o método do controlador recebe apenas o ID e não os demais campos da entidade.

Para resolver isso, me parece que a saída mais direta seria primeira recuperar a entidade original para que ela contenha os campos necessários, assim:

```
division = divisionService.find(id);
divisionService.delete(division);
```

Em JPA é comum esse tipo de coisa. Talvez você não saiba que um objeto somente é uma entidade JPA se ele estiver no contexto do JPA. O parâmetro `Division` do seu método controlador é um objeto comum. Ele só será uma entidade gerenciada se você recuperar os dados pelo `EntityManager` ou se usar o `merge`. Porém este último irá substituir os valores do registro no banco pelos valores do novo objeto, que neste caso estão nulos.

Comment: Obrigado Luiz pela ajuda, desse jeito que vc fez funcionou certinho.